# How to make DIV absorbing space

Tags: css

I have a rather trivial task. 3 DIVs with different backgrounds: 1st - top appendix, 2nd - bottom appednix, and 3rd - repeating background. When I leaving content inside this 3 wrappers I've spacers from top and bottom which I can't remove using negative margins. Well, the CSS is:

```
.cBlock {
    background: url('top.png') no-repeat center top;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.cBlock .inner1 {
    background: url('bottom.png') no-repeat center bottom;
    padding-bottom: 130px;
}

.cBlock .inner2 {
    background: url('bg.png') repeat-y center;
    min-height: 250px;
}

.cBlock .inner3 {
    margin-bottom: -130px;
}
```

HTML is:

```
    <div class="cBlock"><div class="inner1"><div class="inner2"><div class="inner3">
        123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>
    </div></div></div></div>
```

[And results is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScK8o.png)

Comment: so what exactly the problem is? min-height will extend your div if content is less than 250px long

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the first and last `DIV`'s immediately.

```
<div class="cBlock">

    <div class="top"></div>

    <div class="content">
        123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Now you could position those elements directly (`position`) or you can use padding and negative margins.

This is also something you could achieve with CSS:

```
<div class="content">
    123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>123<br>
</div>

/* styling */
.content:before {}
.content {}
.content:after {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset you line-height to `line-height:0px` to parent and `line-height:normal` to child
All right !